# Where can I learn how to GET and POST with python and neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, py2neo

The statement of my problem:
I have this site on a localhost where a user can input its name, skills etc. The database is a graph DB stored in neo4j, also on a localhost. When a user input something there is a routine in java script (not written by me) where the methods GET and POST integrates the database with the site. What I want to do: I want to wirte this routine in python and I am using the library py2neo (but someone recommended the library neo4j, which have oficial support from Neo4j). I never did something like this - method GET and POST in python, that is I never wrote any request api in python and I do not know how to do it. I am learning in self-study but I cannot find in the internet any good resource. I want some good resource if anyone can recommend it to me. I read the basics, like the docummentation etc but I cannot make it work when I write the code. I cannot find any good example in the net. Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

I have used both neo4j  official driver and py2neo, both are good.

I personally like py2neo.
You can check the comparison of these drivers [here](https://medium.com/@hisanor714/comparing-py2neo-and-neo4jrestclient-with-some-basic-commands-using-the-panama-papers-data-223a67bbe533).

You can check [this py2neo tutorial](http://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-flask/index.html) by Nicole White.